# Setting up a virtual application to work as subdomain on Windows Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've installed a php application that requires to set up 2 virtual hosts, one for the front-end website and one for the admin panel website. The proper configuration should be as follow:

```
Virtual host 1  www.domain.com    path:Site/src/site/public
Virtual host 2  admin.domain.com  path:Site/src/site/admin/public
```

On Windows Azure I did as follow:

1. I added 2 custom domains: www.domain.com and admin.domain.com
2. I added a new virtual application under the "virtual applications and directories" area and now I have these 2 virtual applications:

```
/       site\wwwroot\Site\src\site\public
/admin  site\wwwroot\Site\src\site\admin\public
```

When I open the address www.domain.com I see what I'm supposed to see as front end website. If I open the address www.domain.com/admin the admin panel is not working properly because it's supposed to be set up as subdomain and not as subdirectory.

Now I need to map http://www.domain.com/admin so that il looks like http://admin.domain.com

Any ideas of what needs to be done to make this type of configuration work on Azure Web Sites?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map subdomain to virtual directory Azure WebApps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952377/map-subdomain-to-virtual-directory-azure-webapps)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you're not configuring things at the right level. In fact, the good news is that you don't have to configure much of anything when it comes to virtual hosts / virtual applications; Azure Web Sites are already virtual in that way and run on shared instances pools.

In free/shared mode, you share instances with other users, in reserved/standard mode your sites only share instances with your other sites in the same subscription and same region (data center).

All this means that you can create as many Azure Web Sites as you need, and they will all run on the same instance (at least until they need to be scaled out, which is automatic).

In your case, you'll have two Azure Web Sites: `domain-www` and `domain-admin`.  The former will be bound to `www.domain.com` and the latter to `admin.domain.com`.  Of course, the names of the sites are completely arbitrary, you don't have to follow any kind of convention (though it may help).

Comment: Hi. I would like to do the same as user3123913. The reason is that I will have to pay for one instance of shared layer web site.
The way you suggest, makes me pay two instances of shared websites.
Any ideas on how to make both admin and main apps using the same web app?

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas Because the resources are shared, I don't think it would be fair to other users to have an unlimited amount of instances running at a fixed price (and would encourage artificially complex architectures). That said, an inactive instance shouldn't consume much and thus shouldn't cost much. I don't see this clearly reflected in the current pricing plans, you'll want to contact MSFT directly for details.