# 2021 Follow-up Question to Map subdomain to virtual directory Azure WebApps

Tags: azure

[Map subdomain to virtual directory Azure WebApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952377/map-subdomain-to-virtual-directory-azure-webapps)

Is this solution still valid in 2021? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing as Tony. We have the "App Service" and I want to map a custom domain to the sub-directory which is a mini-web-app using the main app resources. i.e.

mainapp.azurewebsites.net/pages/mini-app

The issue is that I can't just add a "Web App" to my App Service Plan as described above. If I'm in the App Service view in Azure i don't see an option to add another web app. If I try to add a new App Service it wants me to create a completely new one that is not linked to the mainapp.azurewebsites.net

Any advice?